# Android NotificationCompat.Action.Builder create multiple actions dynamically from an array

Tags: android, push-notification

I have a list of actions that I need to create an action based on the type of action.  The way I am currently setting it up overrides the previous.  How can I remedy this?

Lets use:

```
       "actions": [{
            "type":"response", 
            "text": "Confirm"
        }, {
            "type":"response", 
            "text": "Decline"
        }, {
            "type":"info", 
            "text": "More Info",
            "link": "http://www.notifyd.com"
        }]
```

and then:

```
        for (int i=0; i < actions.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject action = actions.getJSONObject(i);
            String type = (String)action.get("type");
            if (type.equals("response")) {
                Intent actionIntent = new Intent("blah blah blah");
                String text = (String)action.get("text");
                actionIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                PendingIntent pendingAction = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, actionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                NotificationCompat.Action actionItem = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(0, text, pendingAction).build();
                notificationBuilder.addAction(actionItem);
            } else if (type.equals("info")) {
                // logic here is fine
            }
        }
```

The issue then becomes: 
regardless of the response (which action of type 'response') is chosen in the notification, "Decline" is returned...

As always any direction, cheers, jeers, rotten fruit ect is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you are using same `requestCode` for different `PendingIntent` and same notification `Id` for different `Notification`.

Notification `id` and `requestCode` for `PendingIntent` should be `unique` to get correct notification `data`.

```
// Pending Intent
PendingIntent pendingAction = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE, actionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


// Notification Manager
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(UNIQUE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Im going to mark this as the answer as it was indeed the UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE...  ```PendingIntent.getActivity(this, i, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);``` Thanks for pointing out, I completely glossed over that aspect!

Comment: Happy to help you :)